# min and max value of input array java?

Tags: java, arrays

I have a homework but I don't know really so much in Java I want to make this code to find the min and max temperatur but I couldn't by using For and If. anyone can help me to find these values?

```
 import java.util.*; // Scanner, Locale
class Temperatur
{
 private static int week;

public static void main (String[] args)
 {
 System.out.println ("TEMPERATUR\n");

 Scanner in = new Scanner (System.in);
 in.useLocale (Locale.US);

 System.out.print ("nr of week: ");
 int nrweek = in.nextInt ();

 System.out.print ("how many week?: ");
 int nrofmeasureperweek = in.nextInt ();

 double[][] t = new double[nrweek + 1][nrofmeasureperweek + 1];

 for (int week = 1; week <= nrweek; week++)
 {
 System.out.println ("temperatur - week " + week + ":");
 for (int measure = 1; measure <= nrofmeasureperweek; measure++)
 t[week][measure] = in.nextDouble ();
 }
 System.out.println ();
 System.out.println ("temperatur:");
 for (int week = 1; week <= nrweek; week++)
 {
 for (int measure = 1; measure <= nrofmeasureperweek; measure++)
 System.out.print (t[week][measure] + " ");
 System.out.println ();
 }
 System.out.println ();

 double[] minT = new double[nrweek + 1];
 double[] maxT = new double[nrweek + 1];

 // Code should be here!






 }
}
```

How I can write the right code to find the values of min and max Temperature  in this case!

Comment: Please read: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236) and then [edit] to improve your question accordingly. Also, please take some time to indent your code properly because it's very hard to read it in its current state.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, lets start off by seeing what data we have. We have the temperature 2d array.

```
double[][] t = new double[nrweek + 1][nrofmeasureperweek + 1];
```

Thus,

> t[4][6] is the 6th temperature reading in the 4th week.

We want to fill up the arrays :

```
double[] minT = new double[nrweek + 1];
double[] maxT = new double[nrweek + 1];
```

I would go about something like :

```
for(int i=1; i<=nrweek; i++){

    int min = Integer.MAX_VALUE; // initialising
    int max = Integer.MIN_VALUE; // initialising

    for(int j=1; j<=nrofmeasureperweek; j++){
        // min of current number and the min we have seen till now
        min = Math.min(min, t[i][j]); 
        // similar for max
        max = Math.max(max, t[i][j]);
    }

    minT[i] = min;
    maxT[i] = max; // storing back the min and max
}
```